# C# Write messages too fast to network stream

Tags: c#

I have issues with reading and writing from/to the network stream.

I think that the server sends messages so fast that it sends two protocols together (or more) instead of sending each by itself. That shouldn't be any problem because I have an header and an end of each protocol. The header is `"CHAT"` and the end is `"DEL"` (the control character with byte 127).

When my network watcher reads the DEL character it fires an event that new data were received. Before it fires the data received event, it checks if at least six bytes were received (Since my header is "CHAT" + Type "IA"(for example: is alive)).

Then it checks if the message is from the type "is alive" which shouldn't fire an event since its purpose is only for checking if the other side is still here (Thats why I use a continue). And when for example two protocols would be send together, it reads until the first protocol ends, fires an event and then starts reading again until the next protocol ends.

Thats the logic which I have implement, but it seems I made a mistake. Here the code of my read method:

```
private void Read()
{
    while (this.isReading == true)
    {
        /*if (this.stream.DataAvailable == false)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            continue;
        }*/

        List<byte> receivedBytes = new List<byte>();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1];

        while (this.stream.DataAvailable == true)
        {
            this.stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1);

            if (buffer[0] == 127)
            {
                break;
            }

            receivedBytes.Add(buffer[0]);
        }

        if (receivedBytes.Count >= 6)
        {
            if (receivedBytes[0] == 67 && receivedBytes[1] == 72 && receivedBytes[2] == 65 && receivedBytes[3] == 84)
            {
                if (receivedBytes[4] == 73 && receivedBytes[5] == 65)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                this.FireOnDataReceived(receivedBytes.ToArray());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would advise against using `DataAvailable` - it only says whether there's any data *immediately* available, which isn't often helpful in my experience. I'd also suggest that you consider using a length-prefixed protocol, where each message header says how long the method is... that's easier to handle than checking every byte to see if it's an end-of-message indicator.

Comment: @DaisyShipton So maybe it could the data available? Because before it starts reading again, it handle the first protocol and after data available is false, also if I haven't read all bytes from the network stream?

Comment: I don't know - I haven't looked carefully enough at the code, but that could be it. You should add more logging to help you diagnose the problem. I would consider having one thread reading from the stream (potentially asynchronously) all the time, rather than only reading sometimes.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I use that method already in a thread. Ik you can't know that since I didn't posted it here.

Comment: But it's the *all the time* part that's important. Don't keep stopping reading (as it looks like you might be; it's unclear). Just have an infinite loop, effectively. Unless you're actually not setting `isReading` to false, which we don't know... (I was assuming you were only calling this method occasionally, and setting `isReading` to false.) But yes, treat it as a stream of data, where you can get data in a bursty fashion.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I can send you the whole network watcher class if you want.

Comment: No, there's no need for that - I've suggested how you can proceed from here, along with options to make the protocol simpler.